# dealing with multiple measurements (or duplicates) in a mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I was wondering if someone can  help me think about this in a simple way :

Say you have to fit a mixed effects model on body fat measurements using calipers. A person is measured using calipers on their abdomen, thigh, back and arm (ie four sites) for a total of 4 weeks.

I understand that this is a simple mixed effects model which can be specified as:

```
    fat=c(12,16, 11, 10, 20, 18, 19, 18, 10, 10, 8, 9, 15, 14, 13, 13)
    site=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
    week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
    data=data.frame(fat, site, week)

    m1=lme(fat~week, random=(~1|site), data=data)
```

But what would you recommend if each of those measurements is taken twice for the sake of precision? So the person is measured using the calipers on their thigh and a second measurement is taken right after this at the same spot (say, to make sure that the measurements are accurate). this would look like below:

```
    fat=c(12,16, 11, 10, 20, 18, 19, 18, 10, 10, 8, 9, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12.5, 15.9, 11.2, 9.5, 21, 17.5, 19.8, 18.7, 9.4, 10, 8.8, 9.3, 13, 14, 13.7, 12.1)
    site=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
    week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
    data=data.frame(fat, site, week)
```

How would one account for the fact that two measurements are taken each week from each site (instead of one measurement per site per week)? Please can you specify what steps would be taken to account for the variation between the two same day same site measurements in the lme model?

Thank you!